# expl3 use string variable when calling a function

Tags: expl3, expansion

I'm trying to implement a function that computed a index based on input pre-defined strings. Basically it takes 2 letters as input, and compute an index.

Building it block by block, I've first wrote the computations functions, and now I'm trying to add the string extraction. I'd like to input a string, extract the letters from it, and compute the index from these.

As is, it doesn't make much sense, but this is part of a bigger project ;)

The input string are `N` and `N`. And the computed index is `8`. Computing this index is working.

Where it fails it **extracting these letters from the input string `AV:N/AC:N`, and calling the function to compute the index.**

If I call the function with static letters, I don't have any issues

```
\exp_args:Ne \__XXXX_choose_mapping:nn
   { \fp_eval:n { \__XXXX_compute_value:n {N} } } % N is static
   { \fp_eval:n { \__XXXX_factor_scaling:n {N} } } % N is static
```

I can extract the 2 `N` from the input string (and store them in string variables, but calling the function like this fails

```
\exp_args:Ne \__XXXX_choose_mapping:nn
   { \fp_eval:n { \__XXXX_compute_value:n { \l_XXXXXAV_str } } }
   { \fp_eval:n { \__XXXX_factor_scaling:n { \l_XXXXXAC_str } } }
```

What should I do to make this call to the function with variables work ?

Here is my (failing) MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__XXXX_parse_value:n #1
{
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
    {
        { N } { 0.85 } % This value will be selected
        { A } { 0.62 } % This will not
    }
    {
        \msg_expandable_error:nnn { XXXX } { wrong-case } {#1}
        1.00 % default value
    }
}{}

\cs_new:Npn \__XXXX_compute_value:n #1 { 1 - (1 - \__XXXX_parse_value:n {#1} ) }

\cs_new:Npn \__XXXX_factor_scaling:n #1 { 8.22 * (\__XXXX_parse_value:n {#1} ) }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \basicMacro { m }
{
    \exp_args:Ne \__XXXX_choose_mapping:nn
    { \fp_eval:n { \__XXXX_compute_value:n {#1} } }
    { \fp_eval:n { \__XXXX_factor_scaling:n {#1} } }
}

\cs_new:Npn \__XXXX_choose_mapping:nn #1 #2
{
    \fp_compare:nTF { #1 <= 0 }
    { 0.0 }
    { \fp_eval:n { round( min( 1.08 * (#1 + #2), 10) ) } }
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% These are the thresholds
\def\scoreCrit{9.0}
\def\scoreLow{5.0}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \category { m }{%
    %\newcommand{\category}[1]{
    \fp_compare:nNnTF {#1}<{\scoreLow}{Info}
    {
        \fp_compare:nNnTF{#1}<{\scoreCrit}{High}
        {Critical}
    }%
}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% ADDITIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \computeXXXXX { m }{%
    
    \str_new:N \l_XXXXXAV_str
    \str_new:N \l_XXXXXAC_str
    % A group allows nesting
    \group_begin:
    % Split into parts (separated by "/")
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tnscalc_splittab_seq { / } { #1 }
    % Check that there are 2 items
    \int_compare:nNnTF {(\seq_count:N \l__tnscalc_splittab_seq)} = {2}{}{FALSE}
    % Get the 1st item out of the list : AV:N
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_splittab_seq \l__tnscalc_tempAV_tl

    % Check item's value
    \str_case_e:nnF {\l__tnscalc_tempAV_tl}
    {
        {AV:N} { \str_set:Nn \l_XXXXXAV_str {N} }
        {AV:H} { \str_set:Nn \l_XXXXXAV_str {H} }
    }
    { \PackageError{XXXXX}{"\l__tnscalc_tempAV_tl"~is~not~a~XXXXX~AV~value}{<help>}}
    % Get the 2nd item out of the list : AC:N
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_splittab_seq \l__tnscalc_tempAC_tl
    \str_case_e:nnF {\l__tnscalc_tempAC_tl}
    {
        {AC:N} { \str_set:Nn \l_XXXXXAC_str {N} }
        {AC:H} { \str_set:Nn \l_XXXXXAC_str {H} }
    }
    { \PackageError{XXXXX}{"\l__tnscalc_tempAC_tl"~is~not~a~XXXXX~AC~value}{<help>}}
    
%   \str_show:N \l_XXXXXAV_str
%   \str_show:N \l_XXXXXAC_str

%   % THIS WORKS BUT IS STATIC
%   \exp_args:Ne \__XXXX_choose_mapping:nn
%   { \fp_eval:n { \__XXXX_compute_value:n {N} } }
%   { \fp_eval:n { \__XXXX_factor_scaling:n {N} } }
    
    % THIS DOES NOT WORK    
    \exp_args:Ne \__XXXX_choose_mapping:nn
    { \fp_eval:n { \__XXXX_compute_value:n { \l_XXXXXAV_str } } }
    { \fp_eval:n { \__XXXX_factor_scaling:n { \l_XXXXXAC_str } } }
    
    \group_end:
}%




\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \edef\x{\basicMacro{N}}
    
    \texttt{\meaning\x}
    
    \category{\x}
    
    \category{\basicMacro{N}}
    
    ------
    
    \computeXXXXX{AV:N/AC:N} % FAILING LINE
    
    \category{\computeXXXXX{AV:N/AC:N}} % FAILING LINE
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: \__XXXX_compute_value:V  \l_XXXXXAV_str

Comment: `\computeXXXXX` isn't expandable: you've got a group, assignments, etc.: none of these are marked with a star in `interface3`.

Comment: Is there a way to make it expandable ?

Comment: to make it expandable you'd have to remove all assingments and groups and non expandable error messages. It may be possible but you'd want to start from a high level specification, but possibly simpler, starting from where you are: keep it non expandable but return the answer in a result macro which you can use rather than inline calls. See how tikz/pgf uses `\pgfmathresult`  so a non-expandable function produces  macro which can be used via expansion

Comment: Apart from the fact that it's not expandable, what prevents the call to another function with stored variables ?

Comment: well nothing but that is a fundamental block. In your calling function you have `\fp_compare:nNnTF {#1}`  so `#1` needs to be a number, you can do `\category{5}` but you can not do `\category{\def\foo{5}\foo}` as `\def\foo{5}\foo` does not expand to a number, but you can do `\def\foo{5} \category{\foo}` as `\foo` does expand to 5, hence my comment about `\pgfmathresult` which plays the same role as `\foo`

Comment: Solved it by changing implementation to rely only on expandable functions. Thanks!